# In magento 2 how to add custom options in action apply field in cart price rule form in admin

Tags: magento2, custom-options, shopping-cart-price-rules

In magento 2 how to add custom options in action apply field in cart price rule form in admin

In admin panel -> marketing ->cart price rule -> add new rule

Image:

[image]

Reference Image

[image]

Comment: Thanks @DivyaSekar. Happy to help !! Happy coding. Okay no problem. +1 for acceptance :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This Dropdown options render from **getMetadataValues()** function which is available in `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider.php`

So, You can create plugin for that because, it's public method. I created plugin for that and get output as like you  want.

Follow this below steps for that :

1) Create **di.xml** to set plugin at `app/code/RH/CustomPlugin/etc/adminhtml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider">
      <plugin name="salesrule-plugin" type="RH\CustomPlugin\Plugin\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

2) Now, create plugin file **ValueProvider.php** for add custom option for dropdown at `RH\CustomPlugin\Plugin\Rule\Metadata`:

```
<?php

namespace RH\CustomPlugin\Plugin\Rule\Metadata;

class ValueProvider {
    public function afterGetMetadataValues(
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $applyOptions = [
            'label' => __('Popular'),
            'value' => [
                [
                    'label' => 'The Cheapest, also for Buy 1 get 1 free',
                    'value' => 'buy-1-get-1-free',
                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Get $Y for each $X spent',
                    'value' => 'get-y-for-each-x-spent',
                ],
            ],
        ];
        array_push($result['actions']['children']['simple_action']['arguments']['data']['config']['options'], $applyOptions);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

You can modify option in array as you want.

**Hope, it will helpful for you.**

Comment: Thanks its working what i expect i will  award  the bounty after 21 hours  @Rohan https://prnt.sc/orh99g

Comment: Thank you @divyasekar :)

Comment: how to create a dependency field for  custom options  @Rohan Hapani can u please help me

Comment: can you please help me how to use the custom option  action in  frontend (cart page)

Comment: Yeah sure. Let me check that.

Comment: can you please help me to resolve this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290067/error-in-add-or-update-a-cart-in-magento-2

Comment: Have you got the solution? After adding those option did the discount applied?

Comment: It just displays added options in the select. For implementation or business logic, code needs to be written.

Comment: It's work. Thank you Rohan for your dedication.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer does not works! You need to make below corrections in above code.

```
$applyOptions = [
        [
            'label' => __('Gift with purchase (order level)'),
            'value' => 'gift-with-purchase-order-level',
        ],
        [
            'label' => __('Gift with purchase (item level)'),
            'value' => 'gift-with-purchase-item-level',
        ],
        [
            'label' => __('New Order Creation (free)'),
            'value' => 'new-order-creation-free',
        ],
        [
            'label' => __('New Order Creation (discount)'),
            'value' => 'new-order-creation-discount',
        ],
    ];
    foreach($applyOptions as $optionArr) {
       array_push($result['actions']['children']['simple_action']['arguments']['data']['config']['options'], $optionArr);
    }
```