# Error in add or update a cart in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, shopping-cart-price-rules

Error in adding or updating a cart in Magento 2?

In magento2,  when creating a new cart_price_rule in admin  after an update or adding a product to the cart its shows an error

In admin, i was create a new cart_price_rule  with custom  option action
[image]

Admin:

[image]

Add or update a product in the cart:

[image]

I was check in the exception.log

[image]

I faced an invalid argument exception error.

Comment: Are you using any custom extension to add cart price rules?

Comment: Have you used any extension? this options showing at  Action list is not available at default magento.

Comment: i was added a custom options in action list by this way https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284785/in-magento-2-how-to-add-custom-options-in-action-apply-field-in-cart-price-rule

Comment: No, i was not using any extension, i was a created a custom  options action list by `ValueProvider` plugin

Comment: I need to reproduce this issue in my env and let you know

Comment: wait i will deploy a  extension in github and share the link to you @Ranganathan

Comment: Yes sure.......I can reproduce your issue..working on it

Comment: And also...can you please explain about your exact requirement?

Comment: my requirement  i want to clone like  [this extension](https://amasty.com/special-promotions-for-magento-2.html)

Comment: Ohhh...Ok..But this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284785/in-magento-2-how-to-add-custom-options-in-action-apply-field-in-cart-price-rule is only for displaying in drop-down.. you need to write logic for that i think

Comment: Please accept the github invitation. can you please check your mail or github @Ranganathan

Comment: Custom rule options works for item already added to the cart  but when a new rule is added at the time  update or add to cart not works properly

Comment: Will check your extension and let you know

Comment: I can't see your extn...Did you removed?

Comment: can you please accept my invitation https://prnt.sc/p9qcag

Comment: can you please accept my [invitation](https://github.com/sd2894/app-code-Bootsgrid-SpecialPromotion/invitations)

Comment: @Ranganathan can you get my extension

Comment: @divyasekar - Yes I found the problem...need more time to solve this

Comment: @divyasekar - I cannot found the solution for you and it takes more time...Better you can buy this extension or if it possible to wait, i will update within a week

Comment: Its ok, you tried it lot thank you  so much for your effect @Ranganathan

Comment: Finally i was fix the issue  @Ranganathan

Comment: Oh good to hear...happy coding

Comment: Please  post your answer..

Comment: @aravind i have a  problem within custom option actions  rules. In a `salesrue`  table  i was set a `is_active` is `0` for my custom options action after that its working well

Comment: ok.. How did you overide that file using preference?

Comment: are you asking about which file?

Comment: In checkout cart summary i just used  a set custom  discount  programmatically  and in backend i override a sales_rule_form.xml  file

Comment: Please check this Scenarios in cart price rule https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327406/magento-2-cart-price-multiple-rules