# Magento 2 cart price multiple rules

Tags: magento2

My requirement is
I have extension for the percent discount rule (Buy 1 Get 1 with X% rule) based on that i have created 3 rules below
1)Buy 1 watch get 1 bag 10 % offer
2)Buy 2 watch get 2 bags 20 % offer
3)Buy 3 watch get 3 bags 30 % offer

If i enable these rules only one rule applied but i need
1 watch and 1 bag rule 1 will apply
2 watch and 2 bags rule 2 will apply
3 watch and 3 bags rule 3 will apply
Please advise me?

Comment: hey, can you tell me which extension you used for Buy 1 Watch get 1 Bag with 10% Sales Rule discount? I stuck to applying discount on another product based on specifci product. can you put sample code in answer related to `how to applying buy 1 watch get 1 bag with 10% discount`