# How to validate a custom field in sales rule before the discount applying to cart in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, shopping-cart-price-rules, sales-rule

I created three custom fields in `salesrule` Database Table.

1. apply_on_weekday
2. applicable_time_from
3. applicable_time_to

Now I wants to validate that custom fields before the applying the cart price rule to cart. but i haven't any idea about it.

for example :- first check date. if date is valid then need to check weekday, & then if weekday also valid then check time from & to values.

if all custom field validate is true then after, apply sales rule as normal flow as magento core.

here `apply_on_weekday` field has value as `Fri,Sat,Sun`. convert string to array then validate day is valid or not using current day of datetime of store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add validation for custom **salesrule**, you should add an **after** plugin to `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility::canProcessRule` method.

I'll tell you how to validate the `apply_on_weekday` custom field, then you can extend the plugin class to add validation for `applicable_time_from` and `applicable_time_to`.

Assume you named the vendor name `Vendor`, and the module name `Module` (You can change the vendor name and module name). Take the following steps:

Step 1: Create the registration.php file:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_Module', __DIR__);
```

Step 2: Create the module.xml file:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_SalesRule"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create di.xml file:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility">
        <plugin name="ValidateWeekdayCondition" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ValidateWeekdayCondition"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Step 4: Create ValidateWeekdayCondition.php file.
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/ValidateWeekdayCondition.php`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;


use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;

class ValidateWeekdayCondition
{
    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    protected $timezoneInterface;

    /**
     * @param TimezoneInterface $timezoneInterface
     */
    public function __construct(
        TimezoneInterface $timezoneInterface
    ) {
        $this->timezoneInterface = $timezoneInterface;
    }

    /**
     * after the canProcessRule, Check if salesRule can be applied for the day of the week
     *
     * @param  \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility $subject
     * @param  boolean $result
     * @param  \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule
     * @param  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $address
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function afterCanProcessRule(Utility $subject, bool $result, $rule, $address)
    {
        if ($result) {
            if ($applyOnWeekday = $rule->getApplyOnWeekday()) {
                // $currentWeekday = (new \DateTime())->format('D');
                $currentWeekday = $this->timezoneInterface->date()->format('D'); // get current store Weekday
                $applyOnWeekday = explode(',', $applyOnWeekday);
                if (!in_array($currentWeekday, $applyOnWeekday)) {
                    $result = false;
                }

                // Add new code here to validate applicable_time_from and applicable_time_to
            } else {
                // No weekdays applied
                $result = false;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Step 5: Finally, run the `setup:upgrade` command to make your new module active, and then compile code, deploy static content:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Done.

Comment: yeah, Thank you brother.

Comment: Glad to help :).

Comment: can you guide me in another dout. how can I create `Buy X, get next Y with M% off` Rule. means Buy X qty of one product, get next Y qty of another product with specific percentage of amount discount. I was research a lot to achive this but not success.

Comment: I mean, suppose we need create buy 3 Face wash, get 1 Bodylotion with 10% off SalesRule. it means if customer buy 3 face wash then they will get 10% discount on 1 bodylotion. if customer buy 5 face wash then they will get 10% discount on only 1 bodylotion. if customer buy 6 face wash then they will get 10% discount on 2 bodylotion... I don't think, we can achive this using only condition.

Comment: You can take a look at this post to find know how to add a new action to salesrule: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284785/in-magento-2-how-to-add-custom-options-in-action-apply-field-in-cart-price-rule

Comment: Implement Sales rule action requires much time to investigate and develop, so I'm currently not available to help you with the complete guide. You should dig deep into Magento_SalesRule to know how it implements then apply it to your new Sale rule action. Looks like there is no online documentation for that, if you have done that, creating a new question and self-answer that question will help others who have the same issue.  Good luck.

Comment: ya, I try it first, then I will tell you status of this. & I already added new action in dropdown for that.

Comment: hey brother can you help me in this issue? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/362504/93504

Comment: Hi @HarshPatel Sorry, I'm very busy with my work right now, so I can't help you at the moment, maybe I can take a look after 1-2 weeks... Hope you can resolve your issue soon. Whenever you resolve an issue by yourself you will earn more experience and knowledge.

Comment: hey brother, I doesn't solve my last issue about discount applies on another Y SKU product based on X product Step qty. can you check it please.

Comment: your link doesn't works. it shows 404 page not found

Comment: Brother done I agree. & I will share here link of new question after some hours. Then please provide solution of related to apply discount on another product y based on X product qty step

Comment: brother I edited my last question for discount apply on another product Y issue. please check it here https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/362504/93504 & please help me as soon as possible

Comment: Hey @HarshPatel, sure, I'll take a look soon, but it will take time.