# how can discount apply on another product Y based on X Product Step Qty

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, shopping-cart-price-rules, quote, sales-rule

I need to apply discount on another different product Y based on X Product Step Qty. So that why I was created custom simple action in sales rule. I created custom action class for calculation discount.

see my code below I share

> Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider">
        <plugin name="salesrule-plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Plugin\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Rule\Metadata;

class ValueProvider {
    public function afterGetMetadataValues(
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider $subject,
        $result
    ) {


        $applyOptions = [
            'label' => __('Custom'),
            'value' => [
                [
                    'label' => 'Buy X Get next Y with M% discount',
                    'value' => 'buy_x_get_next_y_with_percent',
                ]
            ],
        ];
        array_push($result['actions']['children']['simple_action']['arguments']['data']['config']['options'], $applyOptions);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

> vendor\module\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\CalculatorFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="discountRules" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="buy_x_get_next_y_with_percent" xsi:type="string">\Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\BuyXGetNextYWithPercent</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
     </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\BuyXGetNextYWithPercent

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Action\Discount;

use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\AbstractDiscount;

/**
 * Buy X Get next Y with M% discount (buy_x_get_next_y_with_percent)
 * 
 * e.g. Rule :- Buy 3 Britannia Bourbon, Get 2 Good Day with 10% off
 * 
 *      Applicable Cases :-
 *          * case 1 :- Bourbon = 3 & good day = 2
 *          * case 2 :- Bourbon = 3 & good day = 7
 *          * case 3 :- Bourbon = 4 & good day = 2
 *          * case 4 :- Bourbon = 5 & good day = 3
 *          * case 5 :- Bourbon = 6 & good day = 4
 *          * case 6 :- Bourbon = 6 & good day = 15
 *          * case 7 :- Bourbon = 7 & good day = 4
 * 
 * 
 *      Not Applicable cases (discount = 0) :- 
 *          * case 1 :- Bourbon = 2 & good day = 2
 *          * case 2 :- Bourbon = 3 & good day = 1
 *          * case 3 :- Bourbon = 6 & good day = 2
 *          * case 4 :- Bourbon = 6 & good day = 3
 * 
 */
class BuyXGetNextYWithPercent extends AbstractDiscount
{
    /**
     * Calculate Buy X Get next Y with M% discount amount
     *
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item
     * @param float $qty
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\Data
     */
    public function calculate($rule, $item, $qty)
    {
        $rulePercent = min(100, $rule->getDiscountAmount());
        $discountData = $this->_calculate($rule, $item, $qty, $rulePercent);
        
        return $discountData;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item
     * @param float $qty
     * @param float $rulePercent
     * @return Data
     */
    protected function _calculate($rule, $item, $qty, $rulePercent)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\Data $discountData */
        $discountData = $this->discountFactory->create();

        $skus = [];
        $conditions = $rule->getConditions();
        if($conditions && gettype($conditions) === 'object')
        {
            $conditions = $conditions->getData();
            if (isset($conditions['conditions'])) {
                $conditions = $conditions['conditions'];
                foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
                    if (isset($condition['conditions'])) {
                        $productConditions = $condition['conditions'];
                        foreach ($productConditions as $productCondition) {
                            if (isset($productCondition['attribute']) && $productCondition['attribute'] == "sku" && isset($productCondition['value'])) {
                                $skuValues = $productCondition['value'];
                                $skuValues = explode(",",$skuValues);
                                foreach ($skuValues as $skuValue) {
                                    $skus[] = $skuValue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $uniqSkus = array_unique($skus);
        
        if(count($uniqSkus) > 0) {
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession */
            $checkoutSession = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class);
            $quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
            /** @var Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $quoteI */
            foreach($quote->getItems() as $quoteI) {
                if(in_array($quoteI->getSku(), $uniqSkus)) {
                    $getApplicableStepQty[] = $this->getApplicableDiscount($quoteI->getTotalQty(), $rule);
                }
            }

            $applicableQty = min($getApplicableStepQty) * $rule->getYProductDiscountQty();
            $maxDiscountQty = $rule->getDiscountQty();
            if(! $maxDiscountQty) {
                // if max qty is not set or zero
                $applicableQty = min($applicableQty, $item->getTotalQty());
            } else {
                $applicableQty = min($applicableQty, $maxDiscountQty);
            }

            if($applicableQty > 0 && $item->getTotalQty() >= $applicableQty) { 
                $itemPrice = $this->validator->getItemPrice($item);
                $baseItemPrice = $this->validator->getItemBasePrice($item);
                $itemOriginalPrice = $this->validator->getItemOriginalPrice($item);
                $baseItemOriginalPrice = $this->validator->getItemBaseOriginalPrice($item);

                $_rulePct = $rulePercent / 100;
                $discountData->setAmount(($applicableQty * $itemPrice - $item->getDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct);
                $discountData->setBaseAmount(($applicableQty * $baseItemPrice - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct);
                $discountData->setOriginalAmount(($applicableQty * $itemOriginalPrice - $item->getDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct);
                $discountData->setBaseOriginalAmount(
                    ($applicableQty * $baseItemOriginalPrice - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct
                );

                if ($maxDiscountQty >= $applicableQty || !$maxDiscountQty) {
                    $discountPercent = min(100, $item->getDiscountPercent() + $rulePercent);
                    $item->setDiscountPercent($discountPercent);
                }
            }
        }

        return $discountData;
    }

    /**
     * get applicable qty for given qty
     * @param float $qty
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule
     * @return float
     */
    private function getApplicableDiscount($qty, $rule)
    {
        $step = $rule->getDiscountStep();
        if ($step) {
            $qty = floor($qty / $step);
        }

        return $qty;
    }

}
```

> Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_rule_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="actions" sortOrder="30">
        <field name="y_product_discount_qty" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="validate-number" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="validate-greater-than-zero" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Discount Qty (Get Y)</label>
                <dataScope>y_product_discount_qty</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

now, In admin panel create cart price rule as same as below snapshot.

[image: sales rule in admin panel]

**-: Issue :-**

Magneto throw error of `Exception #0 (LogicException): Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the looping path` at BuyXGetNextYWithPercent.php:91 line which is `$checkoutSession->getQuote()`.

**-: what i need :-**
I need to get quote data in Sales Rule custom action class without any  Infinite loop error.

How can we get quote data without any issue in cart price rule?

**OR**

Please help me about how to discount apply on another product Y based on X Product Step Qty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run your code, it applied the discount properly without errors.
Here is the result when applying code and all configs like your setting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMn3r.png

Not sure if you created `Session` class by Object Manager directory related to your error or not, but anyway, you should avoid using Object Manager to create a new class in your code.

In your specific case, you can get Quote from `$item` param in `_calculate()` method,
replace:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession */
$checkoutSession = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class);
$quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
```

with

```
$quote = $item->getQuote();
```

After that, remove **generated** class, compile code, and clear cache.

**Edit**
Suggestion from the original poster:
Use `$quote->getAllVisibleItems()` instead of `$quote->getItems()` to get quote item data.
Replace

```
foreach($quote->getItems() as $quoteI) {
    if(in_array($quoteI->getSku(), $uniqSkus)) {
        $getApplicableStepQty[] = $this->getApplicableDiscount($quoteI->getTotalQty(), $rule);
    }
}
```

with

```
$quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($quoteItems as $quoteI) {
    if (in_array($quoteI->getSku(), $uniqSkus)) {
        $getApplicableStepQty[] = $this->getApplicableDiscount($quoteI->getTotalQty(), $rule);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your issue still persists, please post a full exception error trace in your post. I'll take a look.

Comment: okay, I will check it again. but at currently I'm busy in other tasks. but I will comeback & try again it. If I not found any issue then I will accept your solution

Comment: brother can I update your anyswer for share more details?

Comment: Sure, feel free to do that, I'll review it.

Comment: @HarshPatel You suggested adding `$quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();` into the **replace**... **with** section is not correct because `$quoteItems` does not exist in your code. That code should be added to another section and describe that use `$quote->getAllVisibleItems()` instead of `$quote->getItems()` to get quote item data for improvement. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Anyway, glad to see your issue resolved. Cheers!

Comment: yeah, I am also belive in to helps to other people. that why I always try to give answers

Comment: @HarshPatel well done.

Comment: hey brother I have one query can you help me? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/363556/93504

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm currently very busy with my task so I can't take a look your issue at this time.