# how can we increase performance of bulk product save in magento 2 api

Tags: magento2, database, performance, server-setup, magento2-api

when we test performance of bulk product create api request using Apache 2 Benchmark, it takes to much time for return response of request.

I tested bulk api requests with 200 total number of requests & 25 concurrency level

**Live Server Data**

> This is Apache Benchmark Result

```
$ ab -n 200 -c 25 -s 800 <api_url>
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1901567 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking <api_url> (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Finished 200 requests


Server Software:        Apache
Server Hostname:        <api_url>

Concurrency Level:      25
Time taken for tests:   1825.329 seconds
Complete requests:      200
Failed requests:        0
Requests per second:    0.11 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       228166.105 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       9126.644 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          313.50 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        4  259 760.3     87    3458
Processing: 11530 224407 17776.1 227501  242597
Waiting:    11501 223702 17661.3 226799  241997
Total:      11536 224666 17877.9 227903  242602

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  227903
  66%  229995
  75%  231201
  80%  232007
  90%  235161
  95%  236600
  98%  239193
  99%  241998
 100%  242602 (longest request)
```

> Live Server Apache & Php.ini Configuration

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v3 @ 2.60GHz
core 56

Total Memory = 193068 MiB


Maximum Spare Servers = 10
    Server Limit = 256
    Max Request Workers = 150
    Max Connections per child = 10000
    Keep-Alive = On
    Keep-Alive Timeout = 5
    Max Keep-Alive Requests = 100
    Timeout = 300

    max_execution_time = 30
    memory_limit = 2G (*Magento's Min. recommended)
    opcache.enable = On
    gzip compression = enabled
```

**Local Development System Data**

> This is Apache Benchmark Result

```
$ ab -n 200 -c 25 -s 800 <api_url>
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1879490 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking <api_url> (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Finished 200 requests


Server Software:        Apache/2.4.52
Server Hostname:        <api_url>

Concurrency Level:      25
Time taken for tests:   13.566 seconds
Complete requests:      200
Failed requests:        0
Requests per second:    14.74 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1695.800 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       67.832 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          271.61 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       0
Processing:   243 1628 472.0   1657    2864
Waiting:      238 1618 468.9   1641    2832
Total:        243 1628 472.0   1657    2864

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   1657
  66%   1799
  75%   1891
  80%   1944
  90%   2142
  95%   2512
  98%   2631
  99%   2846
 100%   2864 (longest request)
```

> Local Server & Php.ini Configuration

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-9100 CPU @ 3.60GHz
core 4
Total Memory = 11862.5 MiB

Max Requests :- Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts :- Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 5
memory_limit = 756M
opcache.enable = On
gzip compression = enabled
```

---

> Apache Benchmark Result of Live Server with concurrency 10

```
$ ab -n 200 -c 10 -s 800 <api_url>
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1901567 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking <api_url> (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Finished 200 requests


Server Software:        Apache
Server Hostname:        <api_url>

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   1332.961 seconds
Complete requests:      200
Failed requests:        0
Requests per second:    0.15 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       66648.037 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       6664.804 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          429.30 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        3   21  32.2      5      91
Processing: 17982 65490 4646.0  65398   75602
Waiting:    17886 65226 4614.8  65095   75300
Total:      17986 65511 4649.5  65402   75607

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  65402
  66%  66109
  75%  66587
  80%  66991
  90%  70792
  95%  72711
  98%  74708
  99%  75212
 100%  75607 (longest request)
```

> Apache Benchmark Result of Local Server with concurrency 10

```
$ ab -n 200 -c 10 -s 800 <api_url>
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1879490 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking <api_url> (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Finished 200 requests


Server Software:        Apache/2.4.52
Server Hostname:        <api_url>

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   13.210 seconds
Complete requests:      200
Failed requests:        0
Requests per second:    15.14 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       660.524 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       66.052 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          278.93 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:   237  644 126.4    666     933
Waiting:      229  641 125.6    666     922
Total:        237  644 126.4    666     933

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    666
  66%    707
  75%    724
  80%    734
  90%    791
  95%    845
  98%    908
  99%    932
 100%    933 (longest request)
```

---

> Apache Benchmark Result of Live Server with concurrency 3

```
$ ab -n 200 -c 3 -s 800 <api_url>
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1901567 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking <api_url> (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Finished 200 requests


Server Software:        Apache
Server Hostname:        <api_url>

Concurrency Level:      3
Time taken for tests:   1275.103 seconds
Complete requests:      200
Failed requests:        0
Requests per second:    0.16 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       19126.552 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       6375.517 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          448.78 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        3    5   5.0      4      38
Processing: 13393 18910 1324.7  18391   21411
Waiting:    13344 18825 1321.8  18305   21360
Total:      13399 18914 1324.4  18395   21416

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  18395
  66%  19192
  75%  20377
  80%  20592
  90%  20842
  95%  20964
  98%  21174
  99%  21297
 100%  21416 (longest request)
```

---

**Updated :-**

```
Server MPM : prefork
Server API : CGI/FastCGI
```

**Issue :- ** when we send multiple requests at the same time, than why magento 2 takes to much time to respond to us.

what want wrong for me? please help me.

please guide me to improve performance of Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

On your local development server,
drop your Apache Concurrency Level to 3 because you have only 4 CORES.
What is your new timing to completion?

View profile for contact info.

Answer (score 0):

Your Live Server does not have 56 cores according to this URL.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/81059/intel-xeon-processor-e52697-v3-35m-cache-2-60-ghz/specifications.html

Drop your concurrency from 25 to 10 and rerun your test.

What is the new time to completion?  Thank You.

Comment: hey I added benchmark result with concurrency 10, see my edited question

Comment: @HarshPatel Let's try LIVE / Prod server with concurrency of 3 and rerun your test.  
Please post results for comparison.  We will work on DEV on another day please. View profile for contact info.

Comment: checkout I updated test result with concurrency level 3

Comment: I also post Server MPM & Server API details at ending of question

Comment: @HarshPatel Could we schedule a SKYPE TALK session for 5 minutes to review the PROD progress from 25 - 10 - 3 concurrent processing?  Skype ID is  wlhauck@aol.com  Thanks